# How Can i Add multiple customCells (in my case its 3) in a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am creating a demo Application in which i need 3 customCells in a tableView. I am able to add a first customCell in all three rows, but when i add 3 cells application crash.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Create Rows in a tableView
        return 3;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            // First CustomCell
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            if (indexPath.row ==1) {
                // Second CustomCell
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            }
            if (indexPath.row == 2) {
                // Third CustomCell
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhoneTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];

            }
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

when I run the application it crashes This is the error message :  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

Comment: why are you doing  cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1]; when indexPath.row == 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is **cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];** It must be always **cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];**  because there will be only one **Nib** of that name

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // First CustomCell
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        if (indexPath.row ==1) {
            // Second CustomCell
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            // Third CustomCell
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhoneTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhoneTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];
                         ^^^
```

It should be

```
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    if (Your_Condition==1) {
        DoctorListCell *cell = (DoctorListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DoctorListCell"];
        if(cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPhone_DoctorListCell"
                                                         owner:self
                                                       options:nil];
            cell = (DoctorListCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return cell;

    }
    else if(your_Condition==2)
    {

        ArticleListCell *cell = (ArticleListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ArticleListCell"];
        if(cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPhone_ArticleList"
                                                         owner:self
                                                       options:nil];
            cell = (ArticleListCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else if(your_condition==3)
    {

        AnswersCell *cell = (AnswersCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnswersCell"];
        if(cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPhone_AnswersCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (AnswersCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```